# In AWS CFT, how to refer an existing VPC's CIDR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In CFT, I want to create an security group with rule specific to the VPC's CIDR. The CFT allows user to select one of the existing VPCs out in his account.

I used the parameter to let user choose the VPC ID.

```
 "Parameters" : {
    "ExistingVPC": {
      "Description": "VPC ID",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
    },
```

And how can I create the security group like below:

```
...
"InstanceSecurityGroup" : {

"Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
"Properties" : {

"VpcId" : { "Ref" : "ExistingVPC" },

"GroupDescription" : "Open protocol and ports required",

"SecurityGroupIngress" : [

{"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22",     "ToPort" : "22",     "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation" } },

{"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "8080",     "ToPort" : "8080",     "CidrIp" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ { "Ref" : "ExistingVPC" }, "CidrBlock"] } },

{"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "8080",   "ToPort" : "8080",   "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation" } }

],

"Tags" : [ {"Key" : "Application", "Value" : { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId"} }, {"Key" : "Name",     "Value" : {"Fn::Join": [ "", [ { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, " SecurityGroup" ] ]} } ]       

}
},
...
```

I need to open 8080 port IN VPC to let applications to post to the server.

Of course, the Fn::GetAtt doesn't support this syntax at all.

```
{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ { "Ref" : "ExistingVPC" }, "CidrBlock"] }
```

I really appreciate suggestions and maybe workarounds. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It will throw a Template validation error:

> Template validation error: Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute

As per the official documentation, you can not use a variable, since it has to be the logical resource ID of a resource inside your stack. You cannot, for example, use **Ref** to reference a parameter.

[Source.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)

However, if this existing VPC is created by another cloudformation stack within the same region, then you can do something like this:

**Parent Stack Output Section**:

```
...
Outputs:
  VpcCidrBlock:
    Description: ExistingVPC's CIDR block.
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - ExistingVPC
        - CidrBlock
    Export:
      Name: ExistingVPCBlock
```

And, it can be consumed in the **child stack**, like this:

```
...
Resources:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
  Properties:
    CidrIp:
      Fn::ImportValue: ExistingVPCBlock
    FromPort: 80
    IpProtocol: tcp
    ToPort: 80
```